# Why is python skipping the first line of a txt file

Tags: python

So I am trying to create a program where it takes numbers from a file and then averages them. I have tried using float instead of integers(which is what the question wants) but nothing is working. I figured out that it is skipping the first line from the file. The numbers in the txt file are 22, 14, and -99.

```
#Create main function
def main():

    # Open the file numbers.txt
    numbers = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

    # Initialize an accumulator to 0
    total = 0

    # Initialize a counter
    count = 1

    # Read the values from the file
    number = numbers.readline()

    # Convert the value from string to integer

    for number in numbers:

        value = int(number)

        # Add the new number to the total
        total += value

        # Increase count
        count += 1



    # Close the file
    numbers.close()

    # Average the numbers
    avg = total / count
    # Display the information
    print('The average of the numbers from the file is', avg)
main()
```

Comment: `I figured out that it is skipping the first line from the file.`
  
how did you figure that out?

Comment: this line seems redundant the way you've written the code - `number = numbers.readline()`. The `readline()` however iterates once and reads the first line which isn't used anywhere in the code, hence you end up losing it. try removing that line.

Comment: @William all the numbers in file same line or one number per line

Comment: I found out using repl.it and using the step by step debug. I then added a line that would print the total after each iteration. As for the file it is 1 number per line

Comment: Cavin got it. I had to change the count to 0 as well which fixed the issue. How do I mark the post as solved and give credit to him

Comment: You should use a context manager to handle the file object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `number = numbers.readline()`, it reads the first line from the file. When you iterate through `numbers`, it reads the subsequent lines, therefore skipping the line you already read. If you want to read every line, get rid of `number = numbers.readline()` and instead iterate `for number in numbers.readlines()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
def main():
    numbers = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

    lst = [int(number) for number in numbers.read().split("\n")]

    numbers.close()
    avg = sum(lst) / len(lst)
    print('The average of the numbers from the file is', avg)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I figured out that it is skipping the first line from the file

I could see your for loop iterates on file object "numbers" but before that 22 is accessed by variable `number`(notice that there is one 's' missing).

You can get that in below way too.

```
total = 0
count = 0
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line:
            # Add the new number to the total
            total += int(line)
            # Increase count
            count += 1
        else:
            break


# Average the numbers
print("Total: {}, count: {}".format(total, count))
avg = total // count
# Display the information
print('The average of the numbers from the file is', avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the builtin variable `__name__` to check whether the script is run directly.

Context managers (i.e `with`), and list comprehension can simplify your solution.

```
1 if __name__ == '__main__':
2     with open('numbers.txt', 'r') a fptr:
3         nums = [float(num) for num in fptr.readlines()]
4         avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)
5         print(avg)
```